# VBA Replace From Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using VBA codeI picked up online to essentially input a couple of sections and have Excel then edit a Word template, replacing `<oaccount>` for the inputted account number and `<date>` for the date of something, etc.

The issue I am facing is that when using it, the core value of the cell is being inputted and not what you see... For example, I have everything working except the date and the $ amount because when it replaces `<date>` and `<amount>` they show up as "240419" and "3450" when inputting 24/04/2019 and $3,460.00 respectively.

I want to find out how to get Excel to replace the key words with the actual displayed value of Excel.

Below is what I am using to do this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With msWord
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Open "F:\Test folder\TestFolder\Test.docx"
    .Activate

    With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        .Text = "CName"
        .Replacement.Text = ws.Range("C1525").Value2

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
    End With
    .Quit SaveChanges:=True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Format function on the replacement line? Here's a page with a description of it. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php You can also try converting it to a string in that same line using the CStr() function.

Comment: It would look something like this if you use format: .Replacement.Text = Format(ws.Range("C1525").Value2,"dd/mm/yyyy"). if you use the string conversion it would look like this: .Replacement.Text = CStr(ws.Range("C1525").Value2)

Comment: Awesome, that worked than you so much! @TiannaWrona

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I can put that as answer and since it worked for you would you mind upvoting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the Format function on the replacement line? There's a page with a description of it [here](http://techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php). You can also try converting it to a string in that same line using the CStr() function.

It would look something like this if you use format: 
`.Replacement.Text = Format(ws.Range("C1525").Value2,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

If you use the string conversion it would look like this: 
`.Replacement.Text = CStr(ws.Range("C1525").Value2)`